# What should I learn in cloud computing as a .net developer

Tags: azure

I have query related to learn the Cloud computing and Microsoft Azure. I am a .net programmer working on asp.net, C#, Sql server, WCF. If I learn the cloud computing then how it can help me in future as professional growth and How would it benefit me as a developer? 
What should I learn specifically in cloud computing and Azure which would help me in future as professional growth.

Comment: You may have better luck with this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, becoming familiar with cloud computing (even just Microsoft's platform) will help you to understand what is involved with deploying to the cloud, how cloud billing works, and understanding how elastic the environment is.

Specifically what to learn about Azure, I'd do the following:

1. Sign up for a [30-day azure pass](http://windowsazurepass.com/).
2. Download the [Azure Training
   Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8396).
3. Download the latest [Azure SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/) (1.4)
4. Work through some of the Training Kit examples in coordination with your 30-day free pass to Azure.

Comment: hi David, Thanks for your suggestion. Your help is really needful. But still I have doubt that how can it help me as professional growth (What will my demand in market if I learned this). It is at all different technology or it is just a layer above .net technology. So I have to still work on asp.net, WCF, Sql server even I learn the cloud computing.

Comment: Yes, you will still have to learn ASP.NET, WCF, SQL, etc. because those are the programming tools that you use.  Azure is a platform that your application runs on or in.  So you don't have to "program" Azure so much (although there are specific things that you can call for Azure, like config strings and such), but understanding how Azure works will become no different than understanding how IIS works when debugging a problem.  Understand the platform and you becoming a better programmer.  And cloud computing is the direction of the future, IMHO, so it helps to learn it now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to David's answer, I recommend [Azure Fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/paths/azure-fundamentals/) on the free portal Microsoft Learn. On Microsoft Learn there are many courses organized by role. You can just study or take also one or more certifications.

Other than that, notice that as a .NET developer you are not bound to the Microsoft Cloud solution, but you can learn and use any Cloud provider.